# DOM elements in ion-content rendered in wrong direction

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I've build a common static page in my Ionic website (PWA), but I have an unexpected behavior on Firefox : 
All my ion-content's children elements are rendered in the wrong direction.

On Chrome or Safari, everything seems to be OK...

I tried to found a flex container to apply `flex-direction : column` or `flex-direction : column-reverse` but this doesn't worked.

Template and style :

```css
#page-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--ion-color-primary);
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px var(--ion-color-tertiary);
}

#description {
    max-width: 840px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;

    ion-item, ion-item ion-label {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
    ion-item ion-note {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        position: relative;
        left: 60px;
        bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-text>
    <h1 id="page-title">TARIFS</h1>
  </ion-text>

  <div id="description">
    <ion-text>
      <h2>Abonnements mensuels</h2>
    </ion-text>
    <ion-list no-lines id="subscriptions">
      <ion-item text-wrap>
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright" color="primary"></ion-icon><ion-label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Offre individuelle <strong>pro</strong> (18€ HT / mois)</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright" color="primary"></ion-icon><ion-label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Offre individuelle <strong>perso</strong> (19€ TTC / mois)</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-text>
      <h2>Montant des courses</h2>
    </ion-text>
    <ion-list no-lines id="runs">
      <ion-item text-wrap>
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright" color="primary"></ion-icon><ion-label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>Course 20</strong> (50€)</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
        <ion-note>Pour un trajet de 20km maximum</ion-note>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright" color="primary"></ion-icon><ion-label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>Course 40</strong> (80€)</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
        <ion-note>Pour un trajet entre 20km et 40km</ion-note>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright" color="primary"></ion-icon><ion-label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>Course 100</strong> (150€)</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item text-wrap>
        <ion-note>Pour un trajet entre 40km et 100km</ion-note>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

[image: screenshot of the app running on Chrome]

[image: screenshot of the app running on Firefox]

On the screenshots above, you can see in the Firefox inspector that DOM elements are rendered like this:

```
<div id="description">...</div>
<ion-text>...</ion-text>
```

Although in my HTML file it's

```
<ion-text>...</ion-text>
<div id="description">...</div>
```

So I'm not sure it's only due to CSS....

Is there someone who gets similar behavior ? I'll a appreciate every kind of help you can give me :)

EDIT : 
Currently, I'm using Ionic CLI 4.0.3 and this project uses Ionic Framework 4.0.0.beta.2.

Here my ionic info command result:

```
Ionic:
   ionic (Ionic CLI)          : 4.0.3 (/Users/gilhardl/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.2
   @angular-devkit/core       : 0.7.0-rc.2
   @angular-devkit/schematics : 0.7.0-rc.2
   @angular/cli               : 6.0.8
   @ionic/ng-toolkit          : 1.0.0
   @ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.1

System:
   NodeJS : v9.11.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.3.0
   OS     : macOS High Sierra
```

Here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "sambernard-site",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "CYBERG",
  "homepage": "https://sam-bernard.fr/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/service-worker": "6.0.9",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "@ionic/ng-toolkit": "1.0.0",
    "@ionic/schematics-angular": "1.0.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "angular5-recaptcha": "0.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
    "rxjs": "6.2.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.2.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.9",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.7.0-rc.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.7.0-rc.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.7.0-rc.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.7.0-rc.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.5.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  },
  "description": "Site web SAMBERNARD",
  "browser": {
    "path": false,
    "fs": false,
    "crypto": false,
    "http": false,
    "https": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Check your overall app.scss and / or your index.html to see if maybe you applied something app-wide that is causing the reversal?

Comment: I've checked but there is no CSS rule which should cause these "reverse rendering" in my global.scss.
And my index.html is untouched....
Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Which version of Ionic do you use exactly? I cannot reproduce with 4.0.0-beta.3: https://plnkr.co/edit/DEXji8bVf7adK5cq8yKI?p=preview

Comment: I just edited my question with my ionic info command result